# Sharepoint user permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint site where I am the admin and I have full control permission. One of the users created a link on the navigation menu, but I cannot edit it or delete it. The user is no longer on the site. I checked the permission again, and it shows I have full control.

How do I modify or delete the link and its page?

I tried giving myself more permission, but that did not help. I thought full control covers everything.

On the edit mode, some links are editable, but the one I need to remove doesn't give me that option.

Comment: Is this a link to a list/library? or to a URL? Is this a Publishing site?

Comment: The link takes to the SitePages. It's a publishing site

Answer (score 0):

If it is a link to a list/library, it might not be permissions related. Check the List/Library Settings, "Name, Description and Navigation" option:

[image]